# View random error generated from ASP.NET Core MVC hosted on Azure Web App via App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

I have an error page below. The view page returns successfully, the error occurred when a submit button is clicked.

[image]

How to view the error log? What is the quick way to check log, Application Insight, Log Analytics, or App Service Logs? App Service logs are off. Application Insights is already enabled

I notice that it happens every time after the app has been published to Azure. The error occurred intermittently.

**Udpate**

Application Insights is already enabled

```
auzre portal -> application insights -> AI name -> logs
```

Run the query below:

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(10d)
| where cloud_RoleName == "My_App_Service_Name" 
| order by timestamp asc
```

Result:

```
No result
```

Is there any setting missing?  Diagnostic settings?

The error occurred intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

**App Service Logs**(if it's turned on) should be the quickest way, it will display the error messages as soon as possible. You can check the message from azure portal -> your app service -> Log stream.

If you're using **application insights** with app service, it will take a few minutes to send data to the application insights(unless you turn on the live metrics in application insights). You can check the message from auzre portal -> application insights -> logs.

Comment: What's your question? want to see error information in application insights?